# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos[0].title` is marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs

I want to add title to my server as you see in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtQi1.jpg)

its ok to value but its  not working with title, title is in my array as can you se in the picture but its still coming this error, Props is defined in other JS file, så any help here

> 

```
import React from 'react';
import todoInputProps from './TodoInput.props';

const TodoInput = (props) => {
  let input;
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onAdd(input.value, input.title);
    input.title = '';
    input.value = '';

    input.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(currentElement) => { input = currentElement; }}
        placeholder="title"
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(currentElement) => { input = currentElement; }}
        placeholder="value"
      />

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
      add item
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

TodoInput.propTypes = todoInputProps;

export default TodoInput;
```

and

> 

```
import React from 'react';

import todoItemProps from './TodoItem.props';
import './TodoItem.css';

const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const remove = () => {
    props.onRemove(props.id);
  };

  const animateClass = props.animate ? 'added-item' : '';
  return (
    <li className={`TodoItem-item ${animateClass}`}>
      <div className="TodoItem-value">{props.value}</div>
      <div className="TodoItem-title">{props.title}</div>
      <button
        onClick={remove}
      >
      X
      </button>
    </li>
  );
};

TodoItem.propTypes = todoItemProps;

export default TodoItem;
```

My todolist

> 

```
import React from 'react';

import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem';
import todoListProps from './TodoList.props';
import './TodoList.css';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    nextProps.todos.forEach((todo) => {
      const oldValue = this.props.todos.find(oldTodo => oldTodo.id === todo.id);
      const isNewTodo = typeof oldValue === 'undefined';
      if (isNewTodo) {
        this.setState({ addedId: todo.id });
      }
    });
  }

  handleRemove(id) {
    this.props.onItemRemove(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="TodoList">
        {
          this.props.todos.map(todoItem => (
            <TodoItem
              animate
              key={todoItem.id}
              id={todoItem.id}
              value={todoItem.value}
              title={todoItem.title}
              onRemove={this.handleRemove}
            />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

TodoList.propTypes = todoListProps;

export default TodoList;
```

and my contanier looks like that

> 

```
import React from 'react';

import TodoInput from './components/TodoInput';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import { getAll, add, remove } from '../../../utils/todo';
import './TodoContainer.css';

class TodoContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
    };
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getAll().then((todos) => {
      this.setState({ todos });
    });
  }

  handleAdd(value, title) {
    add(value, title).then((id) => {
      this.setState({
        todos: this.state.todos.concat([{
          id,
          value,
          title,
        }]),
      });
    });
  }

  handleRemove(id) {
    remove(id).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        todos: this.state.todos.filter(todoItem => todoItem.id !== id),
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TodoContainer-wrapper">
        <TodoInput onAdd={this.handleAdd} />
        <TodoList
          todos={this.state.todos}
          onItemRemove={this.handleRemove}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `TodoInput`, you try to use one variable `input` for two React instances. Here's the corrected code of `TodoInput`:

```
const TodoInput = (props) => {
  let inputTitle, inputValue;
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.onAdd(inputTitle.value, inputValue.value);
    inputTitle.value = '';
    inputValue.value = '';

    input.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(currentElement) => { inputTitle = currentElement; }}
        placeholder="title"
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(currentElement) => { inputValue = currentElement; }}
        placeholder="value"
      />

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
      add item
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, its working just in the front, but in my backend service in local storage, its not save tilte with value and id

Comment: @user8054244 I think it would be better to make a new question, without the `input` bug and with your new problem elaborated.

Comment: its same code but Im using Axios as connected to my local storage and my code in Axios look like that  'const add = (title, value) => axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `${SERVICE_URL}/v1/items`,
  data: { title, value },
})
  .then(validateStatus(201))
  .then(response => response.data.id);'